# Combine two queries into one - using case when gives varchar error on sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

```
SELECT LOCA_SHORT_CODE AS OUTLET_CD, COUNT (TTD_LOC_ID) AS TOTAL_ADM
FROM #tempTrxnTicDetail WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE TTD_BUS_DATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY LOCA_SHORT_CODE, TTD_LOC_ID
ORDER BY OUTLET_CD ASC

SELECT COUNT (TTD_POS_NO) AS EKIOSK_ADM
FROM #tempTrxnTicDetail WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE TTD_POS_NO LIKE 'KIOSK%'
GROUP BY LOCA_SHORT_CODE, TTD_LOC_ID, TTD_POS_NO
```

as current result is this

```
OUTLET_CD  | TOTAL_ADM
 1. 1U2    | 974
 2. ABM    | 1184 and so on intended result is  

OUTLET_CD | TOTAL_ADM | KIOSK_ADM
 1. 1U2   | 974       | 254
 2. ABM   | 1184      | 30
```

Comment: The syntax is clearly SQL Server, so I changed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT LOCA_SHORT_CODE AS OUTLET_CD, COUNT(TTD_LOC_ID) AS TOTAL_ADM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TTD_POS_NO LIKE 'KIOSK%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TOTAL_KIOSK
FROM #tempTrxnTicDetail 
WHERE TTD_BUS_DATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY LOCA_SHORT_CODE, TTD_LOC_ID
ORDER BY OUTLET_CD ASC;
```

Note that I removed the `WITH (NOLOCK)`.  Unless you really understand what this does, you should not be using it.

Comment: Good day Gordon, thank you for the answer! It worked magically hehe, I was doing it on a production server hence I was told to use nolock most of the time to prevent the chance to increase the server traffic